# How are Fraction Constants Integrated in Definite Integrals

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals

I have a question about double integrals (integration).
For some reason, I find it much more confusing to integrate when I see fraction constants (6/5 from below). I know what to do with the x and y if I'm asked to integrate with respect to x and then y, or the other way around, but I always forget how to handle the parts not directly connected with the x and y (i.e. a coefficient of x or y, or power of x or y, etc.)

$$\iint_0^\frac{1}4 \frac{6}5 (x + y^2) \,dxdy$$

Can someone show me an example of integrating with this situation with the example from above?

Intuitively, it made sense to take the 6/5 and multiply it by the top bound and lower bound as well..but not sure if this is correct.

Comment: The integral operator is linear.

Answer (score 1):

$$\iint_0^\frac{1}4 \frac{6}5 (x + y^2) \,dxdy =\frac{6}5\iint_0^\frac{1}4 (x + y^2) \,dxdy$$

In general, we have the following linearity of integration

$$ \int (\alpha f+\beta g) = \alpha \int f + \beta \int g $$

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to add up to a solution I'm looking at.  If you integrated with respect to x, wouldn't that be 6/5 x^2 /2?

Comment: You also have a $y^2x$ so the inner integral is $[ x^2/2+y^2x]$

Comment: If you have the time..mind editing your answer and showing the work? I do not get that.

Comment: For the inner integral you integrate with respect to $x$ and evaluate, then integrate the result with respect to $y$ to finish the problem.